# I'm getting `Cannot allocate memory` error after mutiple pthread_create calls

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, unix, pthreads

I'm playing with Posix threads and have written the following code in which I create a lot of threads, but reuse `pthread_t` variables for this purpose:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// The amount of thread creation iterations
static const int N = 300;

static pthread_t thread_1, thread_2, thread_3;

void * logic_1(void * arg)
{
  usleep(1 * 1000);
  printf("logic_1 end\n");
  return 0;
}

void * logic_2(void * arg)
{
  usleep(1 * 1000);
  printf("logic_2 end\n");
  return 0;
}

void * logic_3(void * arg)
{
  usleep(1 * 1000);
  printf("logic_3 end\n");
  return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int counter = 0;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        if (pthread_create(&thread_1, NULL, &logic_1, NULL) != 0)
        {
          perror("error: ");
          printf("thread1 did not start after %d threads that were started\n", counter);
          break;
        }
        else
        {
            ++counter;
            printf("start %d thread\n", counter);
        }
        if (pthread_create(&thread_2, NULL, &logic_2, NULL) != 0)
        {
          perror("error: ");
          printf("thread2 did not start after %d threads that were started\n", counter);
          break;
        }
        else
        {
            ++counter;
            printf("start %d thread\n", counter);
        }
        if (pthread_create(&thread_3, NULL, &logic_3, NULL) != 0)
        {
          perror("error: ");
          printf("thread3 did not start after %d threads that were started\n", counter);
          break;
        }
        else
        {
            ++counter;
            printf("start %d thread\n", counter);
        }                      
        usleep(500 * 1000);
    }
    pthread_join(thread_1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread_2, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread_3, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

and after executing I got the error:

```
...
start 376 thread
start 377 thread
start 378 thread
logic_3 end
logic_2 end
logic_1 end
start 379 thread
start 380 thread
start 381 thread
logic_3 end
logic_2 end
logic_1 end
error: : Cannot allocate memory
thread1 did not start after 381 threads that were started
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? I think that I faced with some boundaries or limitation in linux? Will resources for the thread be deallocated or not after each call of `return 0;` statement in `logic_1`, `logic_2`, `logic_3` functions? Maybe I should use an array of threads and for each item of this array call the `pthread_join` function?

Comment: Each thread has their own stack. By default, this stack is quite large, on the order of 8 megabytes. If the thread is *detached*, the stack is discarded when the thread exits. If the thread is *joinable*, the stack is discarded when the thread is joined. By default, threads are *joinable*. Because you keep the stack of each thread you create, you eventually run out of memory. If you want to be sure of this, create a function that opens `/proc/self/maps` and reads and prints its contents using a `fgetc()`/`putchar()` loop; you'll see the stack segments in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call pthread_join inside loop rather than outside so that resources for allocated are released before new set of threads are started in next iteration
If you dont join the thread you are losing system resources as per pthread_join man page

```
   Failure to join with a thread that is joinable (i.e., one that is not
   detached), produces a "zombie thread".  Avoid doing this, since each
   zombie thread consumes some system resources, and when enough zombie
   threads have accumulated, it will no longer be possible to create new
   threads (or processes).
```